# Trying to populate extra in prepareheaders function of React Toolkit Query

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I'm stuck on a problem for a while now and I cant seem to fix it with the help of the documentation so here I am, asking the following question.

Im trying to populate the extra property of the prepareHeaders function and I dont know where to set it.

I have setup an Api slice using Redux Toolkit Query

```js
export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:3001/api/v2/",
    prepareHeaders: async (headers, { extra }) => {
      
      //this is undefined, 
      console.log(extra)
      
      try {
        const access_token = await sec.getTokenSilently()({
          authorizationParams: {
            audience: `audience`,
            scope: headers.get("X-Scope")
          }
        });
        if (access_token) {
          headers.delete("X-Scope");
          headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${access_token}`);
        }
        return headers;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  }),
  endpoints: () => ({})
});
```

The following is how I call my endpoints, for now I pass an extra header, but it does not feel right. I want to send some extra options to the prepareHeaders function.

```js
export const injectGetItems = <T extends HeimdallMember>(name: string, tag: string, route: string, primary_key: string = "id", scope: string = "get:management_project") => {
  const enhancedApi = api.enhanceEndpoints({ addTagTypes: [tag] });
 

  const entityApi = enhancedApi.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (build) => ({
      [name]: build.query({
        query: (arg) => {
          if (arg) {
            return {
              url: route,
              params: { ...arg },
              headers: {
                'X-Scope': scope
              }
            };
          }
          return { url: route };

        },
        providesTags: (result) =>
          // @ts-ignore
          result ? [...result.Data.map(({ [primary_key]: iri }) => ({ type: tag, id: iri } as const)), {
            type: tag,
            id: "LIST"
          }] : [{ type: tag, id: "LIST" }]
      })
    })
  });

  return entityApi;
};
```

It works for now but I want to know if there is a better way. It seems so trivial but I cant seem to figure it out.

I tried passing the prepareHeaders function directly into the build.query function. Tried to pass extra into the endpoints. Im clearly missing something but I dont know what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`extra` is the `extra` of the `thunk` middleware, so you can provide it during store setup:

```
configureStore({
      reducer: {
        counter: slice.reducer,
      },
      middleware: (gDM) =>
        gDM({
          thunk: {
            extraArgument: 42,
          },
        }),
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helped a lot with the understanding of the `extra` property. Will stick to my own solution to my problem for now